# Using jquery, how do I return an element with the next consecutive ID when the elements aren't in consecutive order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of links set out in groups as per the example below.  The ID's for the links are consecutively numbered but the links themselves are not in consecutive order.  I know how to return the href and ID of the clicked link but I also want to get the href of the link with the next consecutive ID and when that becomes the selected element, get the next and so on.  I know how to do this when the elements are in consecutive order themselves but not when they're like this.
Any help would be most appreciated.

My HTML

```
<div id="container">

<div class="group">
<a class="clickable" id="itemid-01" href=""></a>
<a class="clickable" id="itemid-04" href=""></a>
</div>

<div class="group">
<a class="clickable" id="itemid-02" href=""></a>
<a class="clickable" id="itemid-05" href=""></a>
</div>

<div class="group">
<a class="clickable" id="itemid-03" href=""></a>
<a class="clickable" id="itemid-06" href=""></a>
</div>

</div>
```

My Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.clickable').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var this_href = $(this).attr('href');
var this_ID = $(this).attr('id');
var next_ID = //this is the part I can't work out
});
});
```

Comment: Do you need the next id numerically or do you need to traverse the DOM to the next id?

Comment: Hi Matt, I need the next ID numerically.

Comment: The answer I provided should work and also gives you some alternatives that I think will make your life easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, this should do it.  I added the if statement just to catch the trailing zero if the number is smaller than 10.  For numbers larger than 100 you would have to do something similar.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickable').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var this_ID = $(this).attr('id');
    var id_pieces = this_ID.split('-');
    var currentId = parseInt(id_pieces[1]);

    var next_ID = '';
    if(currentId>=10){
        next_ID = id_pieces[0]+'-'+(currentId+1);
    }else{
        next_ID = id_pieces[0]+'-0'+(currentId+1);
    }

    console.log(next_ID);

    });
    });
```

Comment: This answer does work, but I think string manipulation is a bit dubious and if that's how you want to do it, regex is a safer bet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the scope of your markup is in regards to how many elements you plan on having on screen.  Whatever the case, given the way you have it set up you could do something like this:

```
var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
var nextId = null;

//use some regex to get the id from the end of the string
var matches = thisId.match(/\d+$/);

//if it finds a matching integer...
if (matches) {

    //parse out the integer and increment it by 1
    var nextIdInt = parseInt(matches[0], 10);
    nextIdInt++;

    //build the next id string:
    //if less than 10, it addes a leading zero, otherwise just leaves it as is
    nextId = (nextIdInt < 10) ?  "itemid-" + "0" + nextIdInt : "itemid-" + nextIdInt;
}

if (nextId) {
    //do something here with the next id if it is not null
}
```

If I were doing this, I might make it a bit easier on myself by using a custom attribute.  This would avoid using regex or any string manipulation and would make the code a lot simpler.

On your 'clickable' anchors, give them some sort of index attribute like so:

```
<a class="clickable" id="itemid-01" href="" data-index="1"></a>
```

Then your js can simply be:

```
var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
var nextId = null;

//increment the index and store it in a variable
var nextIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10) + 1;

//get the next element
var nextElement = $('a.clickable[data-index="' + nextIndex + '"]');

//probably smart to make sure we found something...
if (nextElement.length > 0) {

    //if you want the id
     nextId = nextElement.attr('id');

}
```

And if you don't want it as readable and all you want is the next id:

```
var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
var nextId =  $('a.clickable[data-index="' + (parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10) + 1) + '"]').attr('id');
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgoodwin/ddheyems/7/)

Comment: Hi Matt,  thanks for your explanation, the custom attribute is a nice touch.  I gave this a try but could only get it to get one link though. I need it to move through all the links in sequential order.  Somewhat like a next button would do in a lightbox for want of a better explanation.

Comment: Let me make sure I am understanding:  So, was the fiddle I provided working in the manner that you were expecting?  My understanding was that on a click of a given anchor, you needed to get the next (and only next) ID based on the sequence.  The fiddle works in that manner.  Maybe I didn't quite get what you were looking for though?  Or if you want to post your code I can take a look!